# How to remove mirror duplicate pair rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

This is my dataframe consisting of columns a,b,c,d. [image]

Here

> 1 2 3 4

has mirror duplicate pair row of

> 3 4 1 2

Removing the duplicate pair should give me [image]

Comment: The pairs are always (a, b) -> (c, d)?

Comment: @Corralien Yes they are. And the duplicates are always (c,d) -> (a,b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['a','b','c','d']],1),index=df.index).drop_duplicates(keep='first').index]
```

U can use np.sort to sort columns in ascending order and then use .drop duplicates to get rid of the duplicate rows.